# Choose a printer when using printReport()

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I have lots of printers installed and I want to be able to print a report on any one of them, without using a dialog box.

So, for example, I have:

JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, false);

But that just prints to the default printer, correct? I need to be able to specify the name of the printer installed on the machine to print to.

Comment: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/printservice/

Comment: thank you for your answer
but this is not what I look for.
I want choose the printer before start printing without 
a print dialog.

Comment: There is `configuration.setDisplayPrintDialog(true);` set it to false and there should be no dialog and it should print with the given printer.

Comment: I have an older version v4.5, this code does not work (I do not find the class SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration)

Comment: it's good, I Locate what I need.
http://europa.estadistica.unam.mx/jasperreports/dist/docs/sample.reference/printservice/
  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution that I found on another web site:
http://europa.estadistica.unam.mx/jasperreports/dist/docs/sample.reference/printservice/
it works very well:

```
 public void print() throws JRException
  {
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);

PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
//printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("Epson Stylus 820 ESC/P 2", null));
//printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("hp LaserJet 1320 PCL 6", null));
//printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("PDFCreator", null));

JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.INPUT_FILE_NAME, "build/reports/PrintServiceReport.jrprint");
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printServiceAttributeSet);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE);

exporter.exportReport();

System.err.println("Printing time : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
  }
```